# PHPSESSID changes in every request ONLY under one internet connection

Tags: php, cookies

After one day of extensive research on the internet, I still can't figure out this one.
What is happening is that PHPSESSID in the cookie isn't persisting from one page to another.

This is happening in computers under one internet connection in a specific place. I've tested several others machines located elsewhere and everything works fine. I've checked session_start, there's no problem with subdomains.

I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I verified with my own computer that this was happening in this place, I realised that when I typed some URLs, they got somehow changed in the middle, for example http://www.medicmanager.com.ar/cloud/santiago/charisma/js/jquery.cookie.js was changed into http://www.medicmanager.com.ar/cloud/santiago/charisma/js/jquery.ckiooe.js, which of course gave 404.

I changed the ISP connection to another, and it started working, so I called the ISP and they told me they've been with this problem for 2 days, changing URLs and messing up with cookies.

Thank you all for your answers, and I leave this here in case someone is in doubt. Yes, it can be your ISP, very strange.

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. Is the time (and time zone!) set correctly on those computers? If it's set incorrectly, they may be discarding session cookies prematurely (possibly even immediately).
2. Is any odd security or "privacy" software installed on the computers? If possible, check if the issue persists under another browser on those machines.
3. Are these computers behind any sort of web proxy? If so, it may be meddling with cookies.

Comment: 1. Yes, I've checked, and cookie lifetime is set to 0.
2. Only Avast, and it's set to normal, nothing strange. Happens both in Firefox and Chrome.
3. No proxies. Just a cablemodem and a router.

The strangest thing is that is started from one day to another, just like that.

Answer (score 0):

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before
>   outputing anything to the browser. - PHP Documentation

Also you may want to check that your php.ini is configured properly to store your session cookies. Either that or call  session_set_cookie_params() every time the page is loaded before the session is started in order to properly configure the session cookie's folder, domain, duration, etc.

> Set cookie parameters defined in the php.ini file. The effect of this
>   function only lasts for the duration of the script. Thus, you need to
>   call session_set_cookie_params() for every request and before
>   session_start() is called.
>
> This function updates the runtime ini values of the corresponding PHP
>   ini configuration keys which can be retrieved with the ini_get().

Comment: session_start() meets the requirements you mention. Also, I've checked the parameters in Google Chrome in the "faulty" computers, and everything's ok. Also, in other computers outside that internet connection, everything runs smooth.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the cookie lifetime to 0 means it will expire straight away, try setting it to another value e.g. 2592000 - which is 30 days in seconds.
EDIT: I meant `time() + 2592000`

Comment: session.cookie_lifetime = 0 ; lifetime in seconds of cookie or if 0, until browser is restarted